# The oauth_verifier is missing or invalid for the Google Reader OAuth Scope

Tags: oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-reader, google-oauth

I was trying out the Google Reader APIs using the Google OAuth 1.x Playground. But I get a "The oauth_verifier is missing or invalid" when I try to Authorize with the following OAuth Scope:
http://www.google.com/reader/api

I believe this is the correct scope. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use OAuth 2.0 for the Google Reader API (you can try it at the [Google OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)). The scope you listed is correct.

Comment: Mark, I have tried with OAuth 2.0 playground as well. All I get is

 <b>401.</b>
<ins>That&#39;s an error.</ins></p>
<p>There was an error in your request.
<ins>That&#39;s all we know.</ins></p></body></html>

when I try to make a GET request to a resource

Comment: I was able to use the OAuth Scope of "http://www.google.com/reader/api" and a request of "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list?output=json" and got back a valid result in OAuth Playground 2.0

Comment: You can also get unread counts with a request to: http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/unread-count?output=json.